# Dynamically populating Subitem -ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

Below is the code where I can dynamically populate the list view and it works good,but I tried so hard and couldn't find the process of populating a SubItem in ListView

**.xml**

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Item"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/address1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Address"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/exit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Bye Bye"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>
</LinearLayout>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Text Goes Here"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/address"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Text Goes Here"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

**class file**

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    EditText et;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        List values = new ArrayList();{}


        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>) getListAdapter();
        String device;
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.addItem:
                List myList = new ArrayList();
                device = et.getText().toString();
                myList.add(device);
                adapter.add(device);
                et.setText("");
                break;
            case R.id.exit:
                finish();
                break;
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

So if you could provide some tutorial or code will be cool and I already read the one from developers.android

Comment: Try with expandable listview

Comment: What do you mean  by "SubItem" ?

Comment: @ShadabAnsari adding two textView